# Select cell from Pandas Dataframe and convert to int

Tags: python, pandas

When selecting cell from Dataframe, it returns me Series value and append it to list as series. How to convert cell into single int value?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['John', 'George', 'Ray'], "score": [123, 321, 112]})

x = df.loc[df['name']=='John', 'score'].reset_index(drop=True)
x.astype(int)
x

list=[]
list.append(x)
list
```

Return me [0    123
Name: score, dtype: int64], but need just [123]

Comment: Please do not use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in general `df["name"] == "John"` could be true for several rows.

A simple way to to work around this is to temporarily turn the "name" column into the DataFrame's index with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['John', 'George', 'Ray'], "score": [123, 321, 112]})
x = df.set_index("name").loc["John", "score"]

list_ = []
list_.append(x)
print(list_)
```

Additional notes:

- If you have "John" more than once in the "name" column, you get the same problem with this solution as in your original code.
- Depending on your data model, it might make sense to use the names as index permanently by moving `set_index` to the line where you define the DataFrame.
- It's bad practice to shadow built-in names like `list` because you might need them later.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
list.append(x[0])
```

returns:

```
list
[123]
```

Comment: Please do not use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

this could help

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['John', 'George', 'Ray'], "score": [123, 321, 112]})

x = df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'score'].reset_index(drop=True)
x = x.item()  # Convert the Series to a single integer value using .item()
print(x)  # Output: 123

my_list = []
my_list.append(x)
print(my_list)  # Output: [123]
```

Comment: `.reset_index` isn't needed there.

Comment: +1: Using `.item()` has the advantage that it raises an error if there are multiple Johns in the "name" column.